# why the list using codeigniter don't show all records?

Tags: php, ajax, codeigniter, datatables, grocery-crud

```
public function ajax_disposisi() {
    $this->load->helper('tanggal');
    $this->jadwal->column_search=array('nomor','tanggal');
    $this->jadwal->column_order=array(null,'nomor','tanggal');
    $list = $this->jadwal->get_datatables('v_disposisi_jadwal');

    $data = array();
    $no = isset($_POST['start'])?$_POST['start']:0;

    print_r($list);
}
```

this code is controller.
v_disposisi_jadwal >> view database.
when I debug the list using 'print_r($list);', but the record don't show all.
please give me some advices..
thanks

class Jadwal_model extends MY_Model {

```
var $column_order = array(null, 'nomor','awal','akhir','ao','ro','workflow');
var $column_search = array('nomor','awal','workflow');

public function __construct()
{
    parent::__construct();
    $this->table='v_jadwal';
}
public function get_detail($id, $suffix='')
{
    $this->db->where($this->table.$suffix.'.id',$id);
    $query=$this->db->get($this->table.$suffix);
    return $query->result();
}
```

}

Comment: You should show the jadwal model. I think it imposes a default limit on query processing

Comment: I've show >>  jadwal model

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've already found the problem solving.
I've found function get_datatables function >> application/core/MY_Model.php
then I see the format how to use get_datatables.
it should be this..

```
$list = $this->jadwal->get_datatables('v_disposisi_jadwal', '', 'status_id IN(1,2,11)');
```